# How to round a numpy stacked array when written to file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-writing

I am trying to write multiple arrays to a file using numpy.column_stack but I cannot round it to two decimals. Here is the reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1.1334, 4.10343, 12.4343])
B = np.array([2.1334, 5.12343, 16.23543])
C = np.array([4.1334, 4.3563, 18.36343])
np.savetxt('data.dat', np.around(np.column_stack((A, B, C)), decimals=2))
```

**Output**

```
1.129999999999999893e+00 2.129999999999999893e+00 4.129999999999999893e+00
4.099999999999999645e+00 5.120000000000000107e+00 4.360000000000000320e+00
1.242999999999999972e+01 1.623999999999999844e+01 1.835999999999999943e+01
```

In short I would like to round the entries to two decimal places and is it possible to tab-separate the entries using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `fmt` flag with a proper format in your [`savetext`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) function, so add `fmt='%.2f'` within `savetext`, and also for get a more elegant result you can specify a `delimiter` flags too :

```
np.savetxt('data.dat', np.around(np.column_stack((A, B, C)), decimals=2),fmt='%.2f',delimiter='\t')
```

result :

```
1.13    2.13    4.13
4.10    5.12    4.36
12.43   16.24   18.36
```

> **[numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)**
>
> Save an array to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the format to np.savetxt

```
np.savetxt('data.dat', np.around(np.column_stack((A, B, C)), decimals=2), fmt="%.2f")
```

Comment: Also this is  what OP needs! ;)